# Flex Chart - Change starting value on y axis

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, charts

Is it possible to change the starting value on an axis for a chart in Flex 3.4?  For example, rather than the y axis starting at 0, have it start at 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a LinearAxis or DateTimeAxis, you can set the minimum and maximum properties. See the flex documentation at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/charts/LinearAxis.html

Comment: The link is bit found.